# What are all the mechanisms used to enable Servant's type-based API?

Tags: haskell, types, data-kinds

I'm very puzzled by how Servant is able to achieve the magic that it does using typing. The example on the web site already puzzles me greatly:

```
type MyAPI = "date" :> Get '[JSON] Date
        :<|> "time" :> Capture "tz" Timezone :> Get '[JSON] Time
```

I get the "date", "time", `[JSON]` and "tz" are type-level literals. They are values that have "become" types. Okay.

I get that `:>` and `:<|>` are type operators. Okay.

I don't get how these things, after they've become types, can be extracted back out into values. What's the mechanism to do this?

I also don't get how the first part of this type can get the framework to expect a function of the signature `IO Date`, or how the second part of this type can get the framework to expect a function of the signature `Timezone -> IO Time` from me. How does this transformation happen?

And how then can the framework call a function for which it didn't initially know the type?

I'm sure there are a number of GHC extensions and unique features at play here that I'm not familiar with that combine to make this magic happen.

Can someone explain what features are involved here and how they are working together?

Comment: have you had a look at the [paper](http://www.andres-loeh.de/Servant/servant-wgp.pdf)? ... Don't know if we can get a better explanation than that ... maybe you read it and come back with detail questions you don't understand - the question here is at least as broad as the paper is long ;)

Comment: The class `GHC.TypeLits.KnownSymbol` and associated functions are used to convert type level strings (`Symbol`) to value level strings. The mechanism is essentially the same for any other type: use a type class. For generating types from other types, you can use a type class or a type family. The question of "how" is quite broad but this is the short version.

Comment: @Carsten Oh. I didn't know there was a paper. Thanks :)

Comment: Hi, I'm one of the authors. The papers was written precisely to answer "how does it all work?" -- let me know if you have more precise questions and I'll do my best to answer them.

Comment: This is a good video on servant: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gMDiKOuwLXw

Answer (score 42):

Looking at the [Servant paper](http://www.andres-loeh.de/Servant/) for a full explanation may
be the best option. Nevertheless, I'll try to illustrate the approach
taken by Servant here, by implementing "TinyServant", a version of
Servant reduced to the bare minimum.

Sorry that this answer is so long. However, it's still a bit shorter
than the paper, and the code discussed here is "only" 81 lines,
available also as a Haskell file [here](https://gist.github.com/kosmikus/03b6ec4a66bceb49b85d).

## Preparations

To start, here are the language extensions we'll need:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, PolyKinds, TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, FlexibleInstances, ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE InstanceSigs #-}
```

The first three are needed for the definition of the type-level DSL
itself. The DSL makes use of type-level strings (`DataKinds`) and also
uses kind polymorphism (`PolyKinds`).  The use of the type-level infix
operators such as `:<|>` and `:>` requires the `TypeOperators`
extension.

The second three are needed for the definition of the interpretation
(we'll define something reminiscent of what a web server does, but
without the whole web part). For this, we need type-level functions
(`TypeFamilies`), some type class programming which will require
(`FlexibleInstances`), and some type annotations to guide the type
checker which require `ScopedTypeVariables`.

Purely for documentation purposes, we also use `InstanceSigs`.

Here's our module header:

```
module TinyServant where

import Control.Applicative
import GHC.TypeLits
import Text.Read
import Data.Time
```

After these preliminaries, we're ready to get going.

## API specifications

The first ingredient is to define the datatypes that are
being used for the API specifications.

```
data Get (a :: *)

data a :<|> b = a :<|> b
infixr 8 :<|>

data (a :: k) :> (b :: *)
infixr 9 :>

data Capture (a :: *)
```

We define only four constructs in our simplified language:

1. A `Get a` represents and endpoint of type `a` (of kind `*`).  In
   comparison with full Servant, we ignore content types here. We need
   the datatype only for the API specifications. There are now directly
   corresponding values, and hence there is no constructor for `Get`.
2. With `a :<|> b`, we represent the choice between two routes.
   Again, we wouldn't need a constructor, but it turns out that
   we'll use a pair of handlers to represent the handler of an
   API using `:<|>`. For nested applications of `:<|>`, we'd get
   nested pairs of handlers, which look somewhat ugly using the
   standard notation in Haskell, so we define the `:<|>`
   constructor to be equivalent to a pair.
3. With `item :> rest`, we represent nested routes, where `item`
   is the first component and `rest` are the remaining components.
   In our simplified DSL, there are just two possibilities for
   `item`: a type-level string, or a `Capture`. Because type-level
   strings are of kind `Symbol`, but a `Capture`, defined below
   is of kind `*`, we make the first argument of `:>`
   *kind-polymorphic*, so that both options are accepted by
   the Haskell kind system.
4. A `Capture a` represents a route component that is captured,
   parsed and then exposed to the handler as a parameter of type `a`.
   In full Servant, `Capture` has an additional string as a parameter
   that is used for documentation generation. We omit the string here.

## Example API

We can now write down a version of the API specification from the
question, adapted to the actual types occuring in `Data.Time`, and
to our simplified DSL:

```
type MyAPI = "date" :> Get Day
        :<|> "time" :> Capture TimeZone :> Get ZonedTime
```

## Interpretation as server

The most interesting aspect is of course what we can do with the
API, and that's also mostly what the question is about.

Servant defines several interpretations, but they all follow a
similar pattern. We'll define one here, which is inspired by the
interpretation as a web server.

In Servant, the `serve` function takes a proxy for the API type
and a handler matching the API type to a WAI `Application`, which
is essentially a function from HTTP requests to responses. We'll
abstract from the web part here, and define

```
serve :: HasServer layout
      => Proxy layout -> Server layout -> [String] -> IO String
```

instead.

The `HasServer` class, which we'll define below, has instances
for all the different constructs of the type-level DSL and therefore
encodes what it means for a Haskell type `layout` to be interpretable
as an API type of a server.

The `Proxy` makes a connection between the type and the value level.
It's defined as

```
data Proxy a = Proxy
```

and its only purpose is that by passing in a `Proxy` constructor
with an explicitly specified type, we can make it very explicit
for what API type we want to compute the server.

The `Server` argument is the handler for the `API`. Here, `Server`
itself is a type family, and computes from the API type the type
that the handler(s) must have. This is one core ingredient of what
makes Servant work correctly.

The list of strings represents the request, reduced to a list of
URL components. As a result, we always return a `String` response,
and we allow the use of `IO`. Full Servant uses somewhat more
complicated types here, but the idea is the same.

## The `Server` type family

We define `Server` as a type family first.
(In Servant, the actual type family being used is `ServerT`, and it
is defined as part of the `HasServer` class.)

```
type family Server layout :: *
```

The handler for a `Get a` endpoint is simply an `IO` action
producing an `a`. (Once again, in the full Servant code, we have
slightly more options, such as producing an error.)

```
type instance Server (Get a) = IO a
```

The handler for `a :<|> b` is a pair of handlers, so we could
define

```
type instance Server (a :<|> b) = (Server a, Server b) -- preliminary
```

But as indicated above, for nested occurrences of `:<|>` this leads
to nested pairs, which look somewhat nicer with an infix pair
constructor, so Servant instead defines the equivalent

```
type instance Server (a :<|> b) = Server a :<|> Server b
```

It remains to explain how each of the path components is handled.

Literal strings in the routes do not affect the type of the
handler:

```
type instance Server ((s :: Symbol) :> r) = Server r
```

A capture, however, means that the handler expects an additional argument
of the type being captured:

```
type instance Server (Capture a :> r) = a -> Server r
```

## Computing the handler type of the example API

If we expand `Server MyAPI`, we obtain

```
Server MyAPI ~ Server ("date" :> Get Day
                  :<|> "time" :> Capture TimeZone :> Get ZonedTime)
             ~      Server ("date" :> Get Day)
               :<|> Server ("time" :> Capture TimeZone :> Get ZonedTime)
             ~      Server (Get Day)
               :<|> Server ("time" :> Capture TimeZone :> Get ZonedTime)
             ~      IO Day
               :<|> Server ("time" :> Capture TimeZone :> Get ZonedTime)
             ~      IO Day
               :<|> Server (Capture TimeZone :> Get ZonedTime)
             ~      IO Day
               :<|> TimeZone -> Server (Get ZonedTime)
             ~      IO Day
               :<|> TimeZone -> IO ZonedTime
```

So as intended, the server for our API requires a pair of handlers,
one that provides a date, and one that, given a time zone, provides
a time. We can define these right now:

```
handleDate :: IO Day
handleDate = utctDay <$> getCurrentTime

handleTime :: TimeZone -> IO ZonedTime
handleTime tz = utcToZonedTime tz <$> getCurrentTime

handleMyAPI :: Server MyAPI
handleMyAPI = handleDate :<|> handleTime
```

## The `HasServer` class

We still have to implement the `HasServer` class, which looks as
follows:

```
class HasServer layout where
  route :: Proxy layout -> Server layout -> [String] -> Maybe (IO String)
```

The task of the function `route` is almost like `serve`. Internally,
we have to dispatch an incoming request to the right router. In the
case of `:<|>`, this means we have to make a choice between two
handlers. How do we make this choice? A simple option is to allow
`route` to fail, by returning a `Maybe`. (Again, full Servant is
somewhat more sophisticated here, and version 0.5 will have a much
improved routing strategy.)

Once we have `route` defined, we can easily define `serve` in terms
of `route`:

```
serve :: HasServer layout
      => Proxy layout -> Server layout -> [String] -> IO String
serve p h xs = case route p h xs of
  Nothing -> ioError (userError "404")
  Just m  -> m
```

If none of the routes match, we fail with a 404. Otherwise, we
return the result.

## The `HasServer` instances

For a `Get` endpoint, we defined

```
type instance Server (Get a) = IO a
```

so the handler is an IO action producing an `a`, which we have
to turn into a `String`. We use `show` for this purpose. In
the actual Servant implementation, this conversion is handled
by the content types machinery, and will typically involve encoding
to JSON or HTML.

```
instance Show a => HasServer (Get a) where
  route :: Proxy (Get a) -> IO a -> [String] -> Maybe (IO String)
  route _ handler [] = Just (show <$> handler)
  route _ _       _  = Nothing
```

Since we're matching an endpoint only, the require the request
to be empty at this point. If it isn't, this route does not
match and we return `Nothing`.

Let's look at choice next:

```
instance (HasServer a, HasServer b) => HasServer (a :<|> b) where
  route :: Proxy (a :<|> b) -> (Server a :<|> Server b) -> [String] -> Maybe (IO String)
  route _ (handlera :<|> handlerb) xs =
        route (Proxy :: Proxy a) handlera xs
    <|> route (Proxy :: Proxy b) handlerb xs
```

Here, we get a pair of handlers, and we use `<|>` for `Maybe`
to try both.

What happens for a literal string?

```
instance (KnownSymbol s, HasServer r) => HasServer ((s :: Symbol) :> r) where
  route :: Proxy (s :> r) -> Server r -> [String] -> Maybe (IO String)
  route _ handler (x : xs)
    | symbolVal (Proxy :: Proxy s) == x = route (Proxy :: Proxy r) handler xs
  route _ _       _                     = Nothing
```

The handler for `s :> r` is of the same type as the handler for `r`.
We require the request to be non-empty and the first component to match
the value-level counterpart of the type-level string. We obtain the
value-level string corresponding to the type-level string literal by
applying `symbolVal`. For this, we need a `KnownSymbol` constraint on
the type-level string literal. But all concrete literals in GHC are
automatically an instance of `KnownSymbol`.

The final case is for captures:

```
instance (Read a, HasServer r) => HasServer (Capture a :> r) where
  route :: Proxy (Capture a :> r) -> (a -> Server r) -> [String] -> Maybe (IO String)
  route _ handler (x : xs) = do
    a <- readMaybe x
    route (Proxy :: Proxy r) (handler a) xs
  route _ _       _        = Nothing
```

In this case, we can assume that our handler is actually a function that
expects an `a`. We require the first component of the request to be parseable
as an `a`. Here, we use `Read`, whereas in Servant, we use the content type
machinery again. If reading fails, we consider the request not to match.
Otherwise, we can feed it to the handler and continue.

## Testing everything

Now we're done.

We can confirm that everything works in GHCi:

```
GHCi> serve (Proxy :: Proxy MyAPI) handleMyAPI  ["time", "CET"]
"2015-11-01 20:25:04.594003 CET"
GHCi> serve (Proxy :: Proxy MyAPI) handleMyAPI  ["time", "12"]
*** Exception: user error (404)
GHCi> serve (Proxy :: Proxy MyAPI) handleMyAPI  ["date"]
"2015-11-01"
GHCi> serve (Proxy :: Proxy MyAPI) handleMyAPI  []
*** Exception: user error (404)
```